# Plugin dev with Sendinblue mailer integration

Tags: plugin-development

I am trying to integrate with `sendinblue API` and I installed it with [composer](https://github.com/mailin-api/mailin-api-php) as a third party library.
But it still does not work:
`Fatal error: Class 'Mailin' not found in /localfolder/www/craft/plugins/stepsprogram/controllers/StepsProgramController.php on line 225`

Here is the `composer.json` file at the root of my plugin:

```
{
    "name": "/stepsprogram",
    "description": "Steps Program.",
    "type": "craft-plugin",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "~1.0",
        "mailin-api/mailin-api-php": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

The `init` function of my plugin:

```
public function init()
{
    // If using composer
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

And the error happen here when trying to call the `mailin` class in my controller:

```
        $mailin = new \Mailin('https://api.sendinblue.com/v2.0', 'dqsdsapicode', 5000);    //Optional parameter: Timeout in MS
        var_dump($mailin->get_account());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Looks like](https://github.com/mailin-api/mailin-api-php/blob/master/src/Sendinblue/Mailin.php) you're missing the proper namespace.

Should be:

```
$mailin = new \Sendinblue\Mailin('https://api.sendinblue.com/v2.0', 'dqsdsapicode', 5000);
```

And here also is the other syntax for a global call in the controller.
Controller beginning would be:

```
<?php
namespace Craft;

use Sendinblue\Mailin;

class FooController extends BaseController
```

Then class call will be:

```
$mailin = new Mailin('https://api.sendinblue.com/v2.0', 'dqsdsapicode', 5000);
```